# Limits of uv unwrapping in blender 2.80

Tags: uv, texture-baking, performance

I've been researching how Blender uses the CPU. It seems each algorithm is different where some may use all cpu cores, others may only use 1 or 2 cores.

I am trying to unwrap a very high poly count model from Photogrammetry software. ~9 million faces.

I am using 'Smart Uv Project'. I have also tried normal Unwrap method.

however, the cpu usage starts at around 20% and then crawls to almost no activity and the program becomes immediately unresponsive.

after a few hours the cpu usage sticks to around 4% and doesnt change from then on out.

Is this normal? Is this a limit of Blender?

Thank you!

Model Poly Count: 
[image: Poly Count]

Resource Monitor after about 5 hours:
[image: Blender only using 4% of CPU]

My machine:

> Ryzen 9 3900X ( 12 cores / 24 threads ), Dual Geforce GTX 1070 GPU 8GB
>   , all SSD, 64GB of ram
>
> Blender v2.80

Comment: 9 Million pieces is extremely high for one model, you should make a retopology before UV Unwrap in order to reduce the amount of polygons and have a better and more manageable object. Think about this: a Transformer robot (from the movies) is around 900 Thousands faces and they look amazing in 4K.

Comment: I know its extremely high. thanks for responding. This is the master hi-res mesh used to create all the derivative decimated meshes for web or 3d print. So its important to keep as much of the detail as possible.

Comment: I am wondering if anyone knows what the limits are for blender?

Comment: As far as i know, Blender can handle 45 million polygons, but everything depends on the hardware specs